# appWidget Orientation Code

Tags: android, android-widget, screen-orientation, android-appwidget

I have code in an appwidget that I want to run when the phone's orientation changes on the home screen, ie like when the keyboard flips out. I have an image that I want to change in an imageview in my appwidget. I can't use different layouts linked to the orientation (ie "layout" and "layout-land") because I don't know the name of the image file until runtime, it is created at runtime. Is there anyway to trigger code to run only if the home screen is shown, my appwidget is active and the orientation just changed?

I could listen for a configuration_change broadcast but that will run everytime the phone switches to landscape or portrait and I only want it to happen when the homescreen is shown. I cannot think of any good way in android to do this. Thanks

Ryan

Comment: Is there anyway to know if the homescreen is on the top of the activity stack? or find out what is?

Comment: In theory yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285410/android-detect-if-an-activity-is-on-the-top-of-the-history-stack, but the home screen is a specific Activity, which will probably be different depending on the device you are using.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a good way of doing this for images generated at runtime.

One approach would be to build both versions of the image and have two ImageViews that are visible depending on the layout/layout-land being used.  (So the RemoteViews would update both ImageViews, but only the correct one would be visible.)

Answer (score 0):

Jeff, what is the reason for this limitation ? I would love to be able to use images generated at runtime, or construct the RemoteView on the runtime as well, rather than use the precompiled XML - this is so inflexible.

Answer (score 0):

There is more info at http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/0eb7c016be05e0b9/d31b312e2fa8530d

Basically update the widget from onConfigurationChanged() in an Activity and add android:configChanges="orientation" for that Activity in your manifest.  Bad thing is, this doesn't cover all use cases.

Comment: You could use a Service instead of an Activity to do it.
That would cover more use cases for sure, but there is still the case where there is an AppWidget and you app is shutdown.