# Android detect if an activity is on the top of the history stack

Tags: android

From a parent class of an activity is there anyway to figure out if the child is on the top of the history stack. I need to perform an action on all of my activities in onPause, but only if the activity is running onPause and it is the top activity. This might happen if the user clicks the home button but not when an activity launches a new activity and thus calls its own onPause. Any ideas would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) includes a [getRunningTasks()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29) method that will give you all of the currently active tasks: *Return a list of the tasks that are currently running, with the most recent being first and older ones after in order. Note that "running" does not mean any of the task's code is currently loaded or activity -- the task may have been frozen by the system, so that it can be restarted in its previous state when next brought to the foreground*.

The data returned is a list of [ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo.html), each of which includes the [ComponentName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html) to derive the activity it represents.